# Angular ui-router shows old stale data after transition back to state

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

We have an ASP.NET MVC 5 application which uses ui-router AngularJS module.

When we go back to a state that has already been loaded, it always shows the old data until we do a full page refresh.

For example:

- User clicks 'View Profile', we show the "ViewProfile" state, a page displaying the profile
- User clicks "Edit Profile", we show the "EditProfile" state, a page with fields to edit the profile
- User makes changes and clicks 'Save', they are then moved back to the "ViewProfile" state
- When "ViewProfile" state loads, it still shows the old data before the edits

How can we force ui-route to pull fresh data any time it loads any state?

**Angular config**

```
var app = angular.module("MyApp", ['ngIdle', 'ui.router'])
    .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider',
        function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
            // Configure client-side routing
            $locationProvider.hashPrefix("!").html5Mode(true);
            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

            $stateProvider
                .state('Home', {
                    url: '/',
                    views: {
                        "mainContainer": {
                            templateUrl: function (params) { return 'Home/Index'; }
                        }
                    }
                })                    
                .state('ProfileManagement', {
                    url: '/ProfileManagement-{action}',
                    views: {
                        "mainContainer": {
                            templateUrl: function (params) { return 'ProfileManagement/' + params.action; }
                        }
                    }
                })
        }]);
```

**How we are doing the transition**

```
$state.go(stateName, { action: actionName }, { reload: true, inherit: false, notify: true });
```

**EDIT w/ Solution**
Since all the functionality is written using jQuery, we cannot use Angular controllers to control the data. Our solution was to completely disable Angular template caching with the following code:

```
app.run(function ($rootScope, $templateCache) {
        $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {
            $templateCache.removeAll();
        });
    });
```

Comment: Old question but have the same problem. I added your code but this time i lost all my global informations. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this work for your problem.

In your angular main page you should have something like this:

`app.run(['$rootScope', function ($rootScope){
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState){
    $rootScope.UrlActive=toState.name;
    });
}]);`

In your angular controller you should have something like this:

`app.controller('AnalisisCtrl', ['$scope','$rootScope', function ($scope,$rootScope) {
    $scope.$watch('UrlActive', function(newValue) {
        if(newValue="ProfileManagement"){
            doSomething();
        };
    });
}]);`

Answer (score 0):

By default ui-router state transition will not re-instantiate toState's controller.

To force instantiation of the controller, you can do this.

```
//assuming you are using $state.go to go back to previous state
$state.go('to.state', params, {
   reload: true
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That is how we are doing the transition, but it doesn't seem to be working. I've edited the question to show how we are performing the transition.

Comment: Could you share ViewProfile state's controller code?

Comment: There is no specific controller for this state. This app is using jQuery for all the functionality and only using Angular only for routing. Basically, after a successful form post, we call a JS function which gets the scope and calls a method on the scope's controller which calls $state.go. I know this is not the ideal setup, but all the functionality was already in place before we implemented angular routing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use resolves, like so:

```
var app = angular.module("MyApp", ['ngIdle', 'ui.router'])
  .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider',
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
      // Configure client-side routing
      $locationProvider.hashPrefix("!").html5Mode(true);
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

      $stateProvider
        .state('Home', {
          url: '/',
          views: {
            "mainContainer": {
              templateUrl: function (params) { return 'Home/Index'; }
            }
          },
          resolve: {
            loadedData: (injectable) => injectable.getData()
          }
        })                    
        .state('ProfileManagement', {
          url: '/ProfileManagement-{action}',
          views: {
            "mainContainer": {
              templateUrl: function (params) { return 'ProfileManagement/' + params.action; }
            }
          },
          resolve: {
            loadedData: (injectable) => injectable.getData()
          }
        })
    }]);
```

In each state, there is a resolve, calling the method 'getData()' in the injectable service (I'm saying a 'service' because that's where we would have the data loaded from).

Then for each state's controller, it will have access to the loadedData resolve; the data will already be loaded at that point and be usable by that controller. So for your case scenario, going back to the state you've come from, the newly updated data will be loaded again and available in that state again.

Keep your state transition the same, with the reload: true, as that is what you want as well.

Comment: Will this work even if the state doesn't have a specific controller defined? I tried adding this "resolve" property in my state definition, but it doesn't allow the state to load.

Comment: You'd probably need a controller for each state yes. That way you could extract the data from the return of the resolve, to use in the template.

Comment: Got you. Unfortunately we don't have that luxury as all this functionality is already written in jQuery :( . We solved this by disabling template caching at a global level (see updated question). Thanks for your help.